# Windows 7 isn't picking up a Wlan Network Adapter

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, bios

My Lenovo T430 laptop running Windows 7 doesn't detect a Wi-Fi adapter
– either in the operating system or in the BIOS. 
[See [image of BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3ve3.jpg).] 
The Ethernet works fine (in the Windows 7 Operating System). 
What could be the issue?

Comment: Are drivers installed and up to date?

Comment: Yes sir, I installed them from Lenovo's website for my specific model of Laptop.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind attaching a screenshot of device manager and expanding the network card section. I just want to confirm that it is actually detecting the card. Also are you able to connect via Ethernet and Windows updates. Depending on where you got your installation media from it may be significantly out of date. I should also note that not every computer will display the WLAN adapter in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not see it in Device Manager at all, then it may have become unseated or become defective. Try restarting the adapter card and/or try a USB wireless card (Best Buy or like Store). Install the wireless USB and then connect

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have forgotten to enable the Wi-Fi service on your laptop. If this is the case, then at first right-click on the internet icon, that is present near to the right-below corner and select "Open Network and Sharing Center". Then, from the left-hand side panel of the window click on Change adapter settings. Now, from the available options right-click on Wi-Fi and then select the Enable option. Now, restart the computer and the router. Hopefully, now as the System turns on you will able to see your router connection in the available network list.

Comment: Nope, it's not there.

Comment: Then the WIFI Card may have been damaged. Or install the specific driver following the model number check its working or not.